# Listing buildings' thematic data with 3D Web Map Client

Tags: cesiumjs, postgrest, 3d-mapping

I'm using 3D Importer/Export to import a `.gml` file to a Postgres 3D CityDB.

Now I want to visualize the buildings on the map and list their characteristics. I've managed to visualize them, but as far as the characteristics go, I'm having some trouble. I'm using PostgREST for serving the thematic data. The issue I've encountered and can't seem to find a solution to is that the 3D CityDB has information about a building spanning multiple tables but 3DWMC queries only one table. When clicking a table, 3DWMC executes a request to the `URL` that I've specified + `?gmlid={the id of the building I've clicked}`. The only table that seems to have a `gmlid` field is `cityobject`.

Here is the configuration of 3DWMP I have:

[image]

The URL is http://localhost:8000/exports/export7/export.kml and the `cityobjectsJsonUrl` is http://localhost:8000/exports/export7/export.json.

And here is the information that is displayed when clicked:

[image]

In a nutshell, I want to display the address of a building (for example) when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I eventually figured it out.

You have to create a materialized view and the query against it.

Here is the view named `view_attributes` ([credit goes to this issue](https://github.com/3dcitydb/3dcitydb-web-map/issues/58)):

```sql
SELECT cityobject.gmlid,
    concat('address '::text, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY address_to_building.building_id)) AS attribute,
    concat(address.street::character varying(255), ' ', address.house_number::character varying(255), ', ', address.zip_code::character varying(255), ', ', address.city::character varying(255), ', ', address.country::character varying(255)) AS value,
    0 AS order_vba
   FROM cityobject,
    building
     JOIN address_to_building ON building.id = address_to_building.building_id
     JOIN address ON address.id = address_to_building.address_id
 WHERE cityobject.id = building.id
```

And then changed the `thematicDataUrl` in the UI to: `http://localhost:3000/view_attribute`.